# CData tags are not getting added when element contains html

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml which is as shown below:

```
<SampleData> 
<SampleGroup>
        <sectionLabel>Auto</sectionLabel>
        <SampleContent> 
            <htmlContent><table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px"> <tbody> <tr> <td>sdf</td> <td>xc</td> </tr> <tr> <td>xcv</td> <td>axcv</td> </tr> <tr> <td>zxc</td> <td>asdasd</td> </tr> </tbody> </table></htmlContent> 
            <contentType>table</contentType> 
        </SampleContent>
</SampleGroup>  
<SampleGroup>       
         <sectionLabel>Dexter</sectionLabel>
</SampleGroup>
</SampleData>
```

My Xslts is as below:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" cdata-section-   elements="sectionLabel htmlContent"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
 <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
 </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

The above xslt adds cdata to section label tags but it doesn't add to htmlcontent element as it has html tags but if I put plain text into htmlcontet it adds them.

So could anyone help me on how to fix this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. The purpose of `cdata-section-elements` is to specify which elements in the output should have their *text content* output as CDATA, but your identity transformation isn't outputting any text inside the `htmlContent` element, only a child `table` element.

If you want the html content turning into text then you need a stylesheet that serialises elements as text (there are examples of such stylesheets in other SO questions), and then you can use `cdata-section-elements` to output that text as CDATA.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to serialize the element, am not able to find relevant post.       Thanks.

Comment: @Dex http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/ is probably the most fully-featured xml serializer XSLT I've found.